# add infowindow for each polygon in Google Maps Api

Tags: html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Im having some trouble with creating an infowindow for each polygon I created. I tried some samples from several websites, but each with no success. Below, you see the code. Nothing happens when clicking on a polygon.

Thanks in advance!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDY0kkJiTPVd2U7aTOAwhc9ySH6oHxOIYM&sensor=false">
</script>

<script>
function initialize()
{
var mapProp = {
  center:new google.maps.LatLng(52.368465, 4.903921),
  zoom:11,
  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  };

var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap")
  ,mapProp);

  var Centrum;


    var triangleCoords = [
        new google.maps.LatLng(52.388828,4.895675),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.388153,4.885783),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.388350,4.884646),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.384329,4.881781),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.382253,4.880483),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.381906,4.879625),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.381304,4.879915),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.374663,4.875784),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.374342,4.875602),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.373425,4.875387),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.372560,4.874572),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.371846,4.874486),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.369783,4.875473),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.368518,4.876739),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.366789,4.877533),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.365911,4.878606),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.364968,4.879249),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.364339,4.879357),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.363421,4.880934),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.363081,4.881395),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.362059,4.881974),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.361803,4.884131),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.360198,4.887403),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.358986,4.889088),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.358331,4.890858),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.357977,4.898744),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.359215,4.904666),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.359726,4.906683),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.360578,4.908271),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.360532,4.910191),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.361266,4.911768),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.362236,4.918356),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.363245,4.919858),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.363756,4.922304),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.366461,4.927154),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.366592,4.931788),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.368741,4.932829),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.369979,4.933022),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.371794,4.932443),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.373215,4.930469),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.375167,4.923549),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.376824,4.913045),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.376785,4.911779),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.379968,4.910975),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.379863,4.905825),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.380963,4.901748),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.383478,4.897081)
  ];

   Centrum = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: triangleCoords,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 3,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });

  Centrum.setMap(map);

var Noord;

      var triangleCoords = [
        new google.maps.LatLng(52.379883,4.905782),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.379987,4.910953),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.382017,4.931467),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.382162,4.952323),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.382384,4.957409),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.382175,4.959512),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.381114,4.961808),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.371748,4.978223),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.370215,4.982150),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.368839,4.987600),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.368302,4.993243),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.368459,5.000110),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.369049,5.004766),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.370267,5.016482),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.375416,5.037661),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.388671,5.079138),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.413846,5.074246),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.416582,5.068281),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.416595,5.067916),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.417262,5.065384),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.416281,5.063217),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.416241,5.062659),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.416307,5.060942),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.416556,5.057788),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.415273,5.050921),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.415155,5.049119),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.416994,5.042574),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.417256,5.040665),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.417380,5.039399),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.418100,5.036856),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.418218,5.036255),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.418270,5.035847),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.418276,5.035461),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.418224,5.035096),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.418074,5.034753),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.417805,5.034399),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.417164,5.034056),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.416686,5.033487),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.416281,5.032479),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.415659,5.030022),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.416169,5.030097),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.416647,5.030086),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.417171,5.029957),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.417733,5.029711),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.418224,5.029399),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.418859,5.028960),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.419166,5.028691),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.419422,5.028337),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.419860,5.027254),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.420076,5.026481),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.420167,5.025612),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.420076,5.024925),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.420141,5.024282),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.420272,5.023488),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.420357,5.023198),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.420763,5.022351),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.421221,5.021610),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.421090,5.021149),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.419932,5.020376),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.419709,5.019765),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.419212,5.018595),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.419140,5.018520),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.419147,5.018445),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.419055,5.018198),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.419199,5.017812),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.420154,5.015001),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.425290,5.000700),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.425447,5.000153),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.425408,4.991366),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.425421,4.990497),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.425480,4.990491),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.425497,4.990427),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.425287,4.990346),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.424525,4.990400),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.423324,4.989107),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.423262,4.988871),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.423275,4.987782),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.422844,4.987096),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.426762,4.982638),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.422824,4.973373),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.421973,4.955971),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.422458,4.955821),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.422209,4.953525),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.423570,4.952388),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.423256,4.951315),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.422798,4.951572),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.421947,4.951508),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.421882,4.949813),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.421947,4.949684),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.421463,4.948525),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.421594,4.947753),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.415652,4.945114),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.414357,4.944105),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.413231,4.939578),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.412053,4.935286),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.411647,4.930716),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.412079,4.930372),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.418584,4.915738),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.418702,4.914687),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.418505,4.914601),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.418519,4.913957),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.420678,4.908786),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.420848,4.907992),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.421123,4.908035),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.421241,4.907563),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.422641,4.904516),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.423648,4.901791),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.424289,4.899645),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.424983,4.896190),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.425467,4.892263),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.425598,4.887757),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.425519,4.882908),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.425938,4.882371),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.426017,4.881814),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.425781,4.880140),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.425794,4.878144),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.426331,4.876320),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.427992,4.874132),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.429510,4.873306),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.429556,4.872737),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.430001,4.871879),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.430197,4.870956),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.430393,4.870731),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.429772,4.869668),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.430275,4.868885),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.430537,4.867973),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.430681,4.866740),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.430668,4.865913),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.430511,4.864916),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.430374,4.864197),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.430289,4.864197),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.429935,4.862673),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.429628,4.862802),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.428777,4.862469),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.425107,4.858210),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.424682,4.857942),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.424185,4.857802),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.423688,4.857899),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.421345,4.859680),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.420940,4.859852),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.420396,4.859809),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.419821,4.859519),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.416981,4.856408),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.414959,4.864905),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.399427,4.886148),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.398819,4.885086),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.393365,4.892768),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.388828,4.895697),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.383458,4.897070),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.380970,4.901748)
  ];

   Noord = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: triangleCoords,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 3,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });

  Noord.setMap(map);

var Westpoort;

      var triangleCoords = [
        new google.maps.LatLng(52.398825,4.885086),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.399427,4.886169),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.414965,4.864926),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.416974,4.856418),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.416673,4.856086),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.417445,4.851397),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.420167,4.831946),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.420697,4.828545),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.428503,4.767519),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.427482,4.767176),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.431060,4.739206),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.400723,4.728756),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.396868,4.757595),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.387832,4.758314),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.388003,4.768882),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.389194,4.769547),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.389181,4.818814),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.387597,4.818857),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.387387,4.831603),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.384820,4.831613),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.385082,4.845110),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.388788,4.844906),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.388815,4.859283),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.390491,4.859283),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.391250,4.858918),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.392102,4.857395),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.393856,4.857309),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.393869,4.856987),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.395375,4.856923),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.395310,4.858553),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.394943,4.860313),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.393895,4.862652),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.392717,4.864304),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.393136,4.866729),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.395401,4.871514),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.395283,4.871922),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.394760,4.871943),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.394838,4.872780),
new google.maps.LatLng(52.394537,4.876170)
  ];

   Westpoort = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: triangleCoords,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 3,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });

  Westpoort.setMap(map);

infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(); 
google.maps.event.addListener(Centrum, 'click', showInfoCentrum);
google.maps.event.addListener(Noord, 'click', showInfoNoord);
google.maps.event.addListener(Westpoort, 'click', showInfoWestpoort);
}



function showInfoCentrum(event) {

    var contentString = "<b>Centrum</b><br />";
    contentString += "Centrum, Amsterdam";
    infowindow.setContent(contentString);
    infowindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
    infowindow.open(map); 
}
function showInfoNoord(event) {
    var contentString = "<b>Noord</b><br />";
    contentString += "Noord, Amsterdam";
    infowindow.setContent(contentString);
    infowindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
    infowindow.open(map); 
}
function showInfoWestpoort(event) {
    var contentString = "<b>Westpoort</b><br />";
    contentString += "Westpoort, Amsterdam";
    infowindow.setContent(contentString);
    infowindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
    infowindow.open(map); 
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="googleMap" style="width:800px;height:600px;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I get a javascript error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: map is not defined ` on line 332; your map variable is local to your initialize function.

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic scope problem. `map` is not visible for your `showInfoxxxx` functions. You have two choices :

1) move `map` outside the `initialization` function, into the global scope.

2) move your `showInfoxxxx` functions into the `initialization` function.

Here is a fiddle with beautified code using option #1 -> **http://jsfiddle.net/9kTxS/**

Comment: Thank you very much! Stupid to overlooked this